# php redirecting to an old non-existant page

Tags: php, redirect

I've wanted to redirect the user from login.php to myPage.php when a certain button is clicked. I was successful using the header command, however now I want to change myPage.php to myNewPage.php but everytime I click on login.php it automatically takes me to myPage.php eventhough the header command is removed, or changed to myNewPage.php. I also tried the header_remove command but with no success and tried to remove google chrome cache, any ideas ? Note: My project partner has the same source code and manages to connect to login.php normally without redirection.

Comment: You need to find that renegade redirect and fix it. Without any code in your question you're basically on your own. If you need mentoring or coaching try services like [Codementor](https://www.codementor.io), [Savvy](https://www.savvy.is), [Hackhands](https://hackhands.com), or [airpair](https://www.airpair.com).

Comment: The problem is the redirect is not in the code anymore but it keeps redirecting me.

Comment: Clearly there's someting in your code doing it. Your job is, like a bounty hunter, to find it and eliminate it.

Comment: There is no redirecting function anymore (tested on my partners PC with the same source code and it didn't redirect him)

Comment: It's not redirecting because the code is haunted, it's redirecting because of a function call. Since you've given us no code at all to help narrow down the problem, this is off-topic: You'll need to work through this methodically to eliminate causes.

Comment: This is the login.php file which keeps redirecting me: https://pastebin.com/TPrTFrbG

Comment: Instead of an external link, can you edit your question to include the relevant code and delete anything not strictly related to your problem? CSS and HTML are probably irrelvant.

Comment: Well I don't know what's exactly related to the problem that's why I uploaded everything. Everytime I reference to login.php (file on pastebin) it redirects me to my old loginSucc.php. That's my whole problem, u can see the problematic file uploaded. I feel like you're trying to humiliate me more than actually helping me.

Comment: I'm trying to help you out here. Don't feel bad about this problem being tricky, we all have days like that. One of the most important things about a Stack Overflow question is having a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That helps us reproduce your problem, identify the issue, and communicate with you clearly about how to fix it. Not having that makes for a lot of guesswork.

Comment: One trick to solving problems is to delete or comment out code that's in the way, and narrow down the problem to the absolute essentials. Often the solution will become apparent.

Comment: One thing that's immediately obvious from a look at that code is you're using some very dangerous, out of date coding practices. A guide like [PHP the Right Way](http://phptherightway.com) can help steer you in the right direction. `mysql_query` was such a huge problem in PHP that they deleted it outright from the language, a rare break with their tradition of backwards compatibility. At the absolute least you should be using something like PDO for your database calls. It's possible you're using a reference or tutorial that's just really old, no fault of your own.

Comment: Keep in mind writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in, so there's rarely a reason to go through the trouble of building one of these from scratch, outside of purely academic environments.

Comment: It is a case of a purely academic environment. My thoughts are that my browser or maybe the server still has the header redirect information and is using it everytime I try to connect to login.php that's why I cleared the browser cache but it didn't help.

Comment: If that's the case, check your access log files to see what pages are being accessed, use the Network Inspector feature in your browser to see the exact HTTP responses you're getting, and try and cross-reference all that to parts of your code. Somewhere in there a `Location:` header is getting set and messing things up.

Answer (score 0):

So I've deleted my project from everywhere and pulled it from my github repository afterwards and the problem was fixed. Still don't know the source of the problem or how to fix it though but if u encounter this situation this is a way to bypass it.